# How to execute a custom writer in Spotfire Analyst?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I am investigating how my team can extend the Spotfire Framework specifically by developing C# AddIns. I was checking out example projects included in the Developer SDK, specifically the "**SpotfireDeveloper.CustomDataWriterExample**".

So what I did is I created a new "TIBCO Spotfire Extention_VS" using Visual Studio and copied all of the classes from the example project. I ran my project (i.e. TIBCO Spotfire Extention_VS1), it loads my Extention fine but I have no idea how to trigger that custom data writer now using the UI (I am new to Spotfire Analyst).

Should I be looking at the File -> Export menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get that working. I had a few problems with my project.

1. I had to add

   /loadallmodules /addmodulefolder:"D:...\10.0\SDK\MyExtentions\Build\Modules" to "Command line argumets" in Debug menu:

[image]

2. I was using Spotfire SDK version 10.1 with Spotfire Analyst 10.0. Apparently, they are not compatible. I had to download Spotfire SDK 10.0 and that worked fine with my Analyst 10.0

The end result, I was able to see my custom data writer export type in the Save as dropdown:
[image]

*P.S.: I have 2 projects that implemented the custom data writer that's why I have duplicates in the export type list*